# Can I declare custom number types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Can I somehow declare custom number types? E.g. I'd like to have a `UnixMsDate` and a `UnixSDate` type, and I'd like if TS could help to always distinguish and disambiguate between these two for me, meaning that I never accidentally mix them up. While being able to convert between them (and to/from number) explicitly.

I tried `type UnixMsDate = number` and it compiles, but it seems to be just an interchangeable alias to number.

Is what I am looking for possible somehow?

Comment: Take a look at [this GitHub proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4639) it is a non-trivial problem but there is continued thought and discussion on the subject.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Using enums

```
enum UnixMsDate { }
enum UnixSDate { }

let date1: UnixMsDate;
let date2: UnixSDate;

date1 = date2; // Type 'UnixSDate' is not assignable to type 'UnixMsDate'.

function foo(x: UnixMsDate) { }
foo(date2); // Argument of type 'UnixSDate' is not assignable to type 'UnixMsDate'.

// All the below work.
date1 = +new Date();
date1 += 22;
console.log(date1 + date2);
date1 = 3.14159;
x1 = +x2;
x1 = Number(x2);
foo(+x2);
```

#### Alternative approach using intersection types

You can accomplish the same thing using intersection types:

```
type A = number & { _A: void; };
type B = number & { _B: void; };
```

This works almost identically, except that you will need to cast when assigning:

```
let a: A = <A>222;
```

It still does not prevent adding numbers of the two types together. [Here is more information](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4372) on this hack.

Comment: Hmm, this is getting close to what I am looking for, thanks! I really like that it catches and disallows implicit `date1 = date2` and `foo(date2)`. However, I'm a concerned that it still allows `date1 + date2`. Can I somehow make the typechecker forbid that too? Ideally it would still allow for `date1 + date1`, but may not be a big problem if it does not.

Comment: I'm out of gas. If there's some way to do what you want, I sure don't know what it is. Of course you could make the two types into classes holding the primitive value.